# Assigning values to associative array (multidimensional)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
while($row = $champions_table_result->fetch_assoc()){

   while($row3['Champion']==$row['Champion']){
     $test[$row['Champion']]['General']['Change'][] =$row3['Stat_Change'];
     $test[$row['Champion']]['General']['Type'][] = $row3['Stat_Change_Icon'];
   }

   foreach ($row as $column_name => $column) {
     if ($column_name == 'Champion') {
       continue; // These fields were already displayed above
     }

     if (!empty($column)) {
       $test[$row['Champion']][$column_name] =$column; 
       while($row2['Champion']==$row['Champion']&&$row2['Spell_Type'] 
       ==$column_name&&!empty($row2['Spell_Change'])) {
          $test[$row['Champion']][$column_name]['Change'][] = $spell_descriptions[          $champion_counter][$spell_counter][$change_counter];
          $test[$row['Champion']][$column_name]['Type'][] = $spell_changes[ 
          $champion_counter][$spell_counter][$change_counter];
          $row2 = $spells_table_result->fetch_assoc();
        }

     }

  }

}
```

To better showcase my problem here is an image with var_dump from $test - array https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHWAb.png and next to Q W E it should show variable $column; I'm trying to achieve that in this line

```
$test[$row['Champion']][$column_name] =$column;
```

Without this line I get what I showed on imgur but with this line I get an error: 
 Warning: Illegal string offset 'Change' and  Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array

Comment: that means `$test....['General']` is a **STRING**, and you're trying to use `['Change']` as a character offset in there, e.g. `$foo = 'abc'; echo $foo[1];` outputs `b`, and `$foo['bar']` will spit out the error you're getting.

Comment: @MarcB well then I could do sth like this $test[$row['Champion']][$column_name][$column]['Change'][] which is adding 1 dimension more but seems like a waste, does that make sense?

Comment: maybe it's not ['General'] specifically, but at some point, $column_name is pointing at something that IS a string.